# A question about the realization and randomness

Tags: r, sample, variance, expectations

I am doing an assignment for my data class and new to R programming. If a fair 6-sided die is rolled, Let X be the number showing on the top of the die. (The first question is involved the R programming)

1. Generate 5 realizations from the distribution of X. Show the sample you generated and the sample mean, sample variance, and sample deviation
2. What is the expectation and the variance of the sample mean in first question?

I have written the code for the first assignment which I am confident that I am right:

```
S_R <- sample (1:6, 5, replace=TRUE)

print(S_R)

mean(S_R)

Var(S_R)
```

but **I have one problem in the second question** is that  Every time when I concluded and knit to PDF, it is going to run as random so that the value will change no matter what. This is kinda hard for me to compute the expectation and variance of sample mean.

Comment: So set the seed: `set.seed(12345)`

Comment: oh my it works! could you tell me the terminology of this?

Comment: It's called seeding the random number generator. It is (in my opinion) a *necessity* for reproducible reporting, as it ensures (or at least *assures*) that the sequence of random numbers from that point forward will be the same sequence the next time you set the seed to the same value. It can be used for evil, though, for instance: p-value seeking.

Comment: But if you need your summary statistics to be included in the knit/compiled/rendered PDF, then why do you need to put them in statically? Let's say you calculate `samp_mean <- mean(x)`, then you can include the variable contents, such as `The observed sample mean is \`r round(samp_mean,2)\`.`. Look for mention of "inline code" in r-markdown documents.

Comment: here is as good a place as any to start learning about pseudo-random number generation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed